# Append text from dialog box in a div below the draggable element using JQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the JQueryUI to make images draggable and resizable. When I double click on the image dropped on the div, a dialog box appears where I can enter an IP address:

[image]

I want the IP that has been entered to be appended above the image in another div.

These are the codes I'm currently using:

**HTML**

```
<div id="configbox" title="IPv6 Configuration" style="font-size:15px;">
    <form>
        <b>DHCP</b> <input type="radio" name="option" value="DHCP"/> &nbsp;

        <b>Auto Config</b>  <input type="radio" name="option" value="auto"/> &nbsp;

        <b>Static</b>  <input type="radio" name="option" value="static"/> &nbsp; <br/><br/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>IPv6 Address:</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="address" size="25"/> &nbsp; / &nbsp; <input type="text" id="subnet" size="3"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Link Local Address:</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="local" size="35"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>IPv6 Gateway:</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="gateway" size="35"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>IPv6 DNS Server:</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="dns" size="35"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
    </form>
    <table>
        <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <center>
                    <button id="submit"
                            style="background-color:#B4BA22; border-radius:3px; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer;">Submit
                    </button> &nbsp;
                        <button id="cancel"
                                style="border-radius:3px; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer;"> Cancel
                        </button>
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
        // matches all children of droppable, change selector as needed
        if ($(e.target).closest(".drag").length > 0) {
            $(e.target).closest(".drag").find(".ui-resizable-handle").show();
            $("#tools").show();

            $('.drag').dblclick(function () { //the dialog box to enter the IP address opens on double click
                $('#configbox').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });

        }
        else {
            $("#droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
            $("#tools").hide();
        }
    });
```

**The submit function**

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
                var enter = $("#address").val();
                $("<div>"+enter+"</div>").appendTo("div.drag"); //class .drag are for the images
            });
```

**Result:**

[image]

As you can see, the IP address is being appended to every single image which has the class .drag. 

How can I solve this? Please help.

**EDIT**

This the new JQuery Code:

```
var currentDragImg="";
$(document).click(function (e) {
    // matches all children of droppable, change selector as needed

    currentDragImg = $(e.target).closest(".drag");



    if ($(e.target).closest(".drag").length > 0) {

        $(e.target).closest(".drag").find(".ui-resizable-handle").show();
        $("#tools").show();



    }
    else {
        $("#droppable").find(".ui-resizable-handle").hide();
        $("#tools").hide();
    }

});

$('.drag').dblclick(function () { //the dialog box to enter the IP address opens on double click
    $('#configbox').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: can you provide the html for this?

Comment: Yes sure wait a min.

Comment: @Damini Dont try to use class here, generate an unique ID for each dragged element and then add the div with IP address to that specified div with the unique ID

Comment: @Damini There will be a stop event for drag action in jqueryUI. In that stop event you just assign an unique ID to that element and then access that element using that ID.

Comment: why are you doing `$("<div>"+enter+"</div>").appendTo("div.drag");` use `id` instead of `class`.

Comment: The problem is, each image which is being dragged to the div has the class .drag. That's why .closest is being used, right? How can I change it?

Comment: Make a global variable `var currentDragImg="";` set it with `currentDragImg = $(e.target).closest(".drag")` and use it as `$("<div>"+enter+"</div>").appendTo(currentDragImg);`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Thanks I'll try it right away. You could answer the question.

Comment: @Damini please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store a reference to the element that was clicked on using .data(), like this:

```
$('.drag').dblclick(function () { 
                $('#configbox').data('opener', this).dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
```

Then to get it later you can grab it from $('#configbox').data('opener'), or $.data(this, 'opener') in the case of the open callback (because this refers to the dialog element). For example:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
                var enter = $("#address").val();
                $("<div>"+enter+"</div>").appendTo($('#configbox').data('opener')); //class .drag are for the images
            });
```

Comment: Is there any jquery error?? cz i assume $.data(this,'opener') will provide you the DOM of source element from which it was clicked and then you can append your text to that div.

Comment: It says `.dialog()` is not a recognized function.

Comment: Hey I tried it again and yours works wonderfully. However, update your answer because `$('#configbox').data('opener')` worked as compared to the one you listed. Thanks so much i'm accepting your answer.